# Is there a way to use Notes without using Mail.app

Tags: notes.app

With iCloud I've found the notes app super handy now that it easily syncs to my iPhone and iPad. It also syncs to my mac via Mail.app, but I was wondering if there's an easy way to access and edit notes that doesn't require opening my email.

Any way to do this?

Comment: I look forward to seeing if anyone's come up with a way of doing this. Apple really should make an actual notes client for Mac that syncs with your iOS notes app.

Comment: I actualy do not like these showing up in Mail, I use them for tiny things like door passcodes or a song i like, I do not need it in my emails as an unread alert in the sidebar.

Comment: I think this was discussed earlier here, looking for Mac OS client to open notes. I don't think anyone found anything. You might try Simplenote which is a nice cloud-based notes client: simple and free with a few Mac OS (besides a browser) clients for editing. http://simplenoteapp.com/

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way to use notes outside of Mail.app as suggested there are other apps like evernote that will sync but not iOS notes sadly.

I would have expected some kind of widget like stickies to work with notes, but no.

Comment: Note this changed with Mountain Lion (or perhaps Lion) There is a Notes.app